# How can I change JSONObject to Gson?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a `org.json.JSONObject`.
And wanna make `com.google.gson.Gson` with using it.

What will be the easiest way to create Gson from JSONObejct?

Thank you.

Comment: _Making Gson out of `org.json.JSONObject`_ does not make sense. You seem to need traversing your `JSONObject` node by node and constructing a new `JsonObject` out of it (don't need to deserialize or serialize).

Comment: Oh... now I understand that... thank you! can you re-post it by answer? I will check this question by resolved